# Calling function from button inside datagrid

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I have this snippet in my MXML:

```
...

<mx:Script source="main.as" />

...

<mx:Button id="works" click="someClick()" />
<xDComponents:DataGrid id="tp_list" width="100%" height="100%">
    <xDComponents:columns>
        <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="barcode" headerText="{_s('Barcode')}" />
        <mx:DataGridColumn width="10">
            <mx:itemRenderer>
                <mx:Component>
                    <mx:Button label="-" click="someClick()" />
                </mx:Component>
            </mx:itemRenderer>
        </mx:DataGridColumn> 
    </xDComponents:columns>
</xDComponents:DataGrid>

...
```

(the `xDComponents:DataGrid` is derived from `DataGrid`)

In `main.as` I have:

```
private function someClick():void {
    // do stuff
}
```

In the first `Button` (`id="works"`), the code works and the handler gets called. In the `DataGrid` though, I get the error

> Call to a possibly undefined method someClick

How can I make my function available to the button inside the datagrid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use outerDocument property to access outside of the itemRenderer.

Example in your case:

```
<mx:Button label="-" click = "{ outerDocument.someClick() }" />
```

Comment: While this works, it's poor architecture.  The itemRenderer is a separate class in its own right, and this approach means very tightly coupling it to the parent MXML class.

Answer (score 1):

The correct solution is to dispatch an event handler when the button is clicked and listen for that event on the data grid or anywhere up the event chain.
The current code is not working because the item renderer is compiled into a separate class and it will not have access to the method you want to call, so the renderer has no access to it's outside, the solution is to dispatch a custom event.
I will not paste an example here, just research on hot to make and dispatch custom event, also pay attention to the bubles property of an event.